# In double (*foo)[2] what does the [2] represent

Tags: c, primitive, primitive-types

In `double (*foo)[2]` what does the `[2]` represent? And how would I convert an array as such to an array of float* in C?

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) is handy for decoding incomprehensible C types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
double (*foo)[2]
```

`foo` is a pointer to an array of two `double` elements.

For example:

```
double bla[2];
double (*foo)[2] = &bla;
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of your question, you won't be able to convert it to an array of floats. You will need to declare a new array of floats and explicitly convert each member.

For example,

```
float bar[] = {(float)(*foo)[0], (float)(*foo)[1]};
```

Additionally to add to the answer of the first part I find this [link](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) and his so called right-left rule invaluable for working out what a confusing declaration means.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually a super essential part of my question. Super helpful!

Comment: @ouah That's interesting, thanks. I would have expected a compiler warning about the downgrade. Still, the cast can't hurt, especially if the code will be run through splint/pc-lint analysis.

Comment: @acraig5075 PC-Lint would report a loss of precision through `Info 736` but C doesn't require the cast as there is an implicit conversion from `double` to `float`.